# switching over cell image to in cell image in Google Spreadhseet

Tags: google-sheets

I have images in a spreadsheet that are placed above the cells. I try to put them into the cells. The [help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9224754?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cmove-an-image) reads

> To move an image from over the cells to inside a cell:
>
> 1. Click the cell you want to place the image in.
> 2. Click the image > More > **Put image in selected cell.**

However, I can not find the menu option "More", clicking the image does not open a menu and [alt]+[/] (the menu search) does not find that command either if I have the cell and image selected. My format bar looks like this, while having cell E12 and the image selected:

[image: Google Spreadsheet bar]

Is the help out of date and where do I find that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"More" is a button shown on the top-right corner of the image over the cells when it's selected.

[image: More button on image over the cells in Google Sheets]

Comment: gosh, those dots are nigh hidden on some photos, especially with dark backgrounds.